# Eclipse - no "java project" in menu after installation JDT plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I was using Eclipse for C/C++ on OpenSuse and installed JDT plugin. Eclipse showed that everythign went fine, but in the menu "File->New->Project" there's no item "Java Project". Something went wrong or should I change some options in Eclipse?

Comment: Is there a java folder in the new project wizard?

Comment: Did you try going to the Java perspective? It's possible that without having gone to that perspective it's not loading the JDT plugin stuff (nearly everything in Eclipse is loaded only on first use).

Comment: @FrancisUpton
Did you mean "Window"-> "Open Perspective". No, there's no Java perspective in that menu and also in the submenu "Other".

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp
No, there's no such folder.

Comment: If you try and use an entirely new workspace (or completely delete your current workspace) does that help?

Comment: Make sure it really got installed, it sounds like somehow it's not installed. Go to Help -> About and push installation details and make sure it's there. And that you restarted after you installed it.

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp doesn't help

Comment: @FrancisUpton in "installation details" section I have 
"Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83 org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group Eclipse.org" - is this ok?